# How to download export csv file like a save as button (data send from ajax request)

Tags: django, ajax

So i want to export a csv file from query (the parameter i send with the ajax function) in database with django , i already follow the documentation , and it seems success, but the browser didnt have anything like save as .csv file and i dont see my file been created by the system

here's the code

html code

```
 <form class="form-horizontal  style-form" action="#">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Database Name</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                      <div class="btn-group">
                            <select id = "tableselect"  style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;">              
                            <!-- <li><a href="#"></a></li> -->
                            {% for table in obj2 %}
                                    <option value = "{{table}}" >{{ table }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}                          
                            <!-- <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li> -->
                            </option>
                            </select>                    
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-theme" onclick="return appendBox()">Add</button>
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Column Name</label> 
                  <div class="col-md-4" id ="test">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                       <div class="btn-group">
                            <select id = "columnselect" style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;">              
                            </select>                
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-theme" onclick=" return appendFilterBox()">Add</button>
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Filter</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4" id="filtbox">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                       <div class="btn-group">                          
                            <select id="conditionselect" style="width:150px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-size:15px;text-align-last:center;">                                          
                            </select>    
                            <select id="operator" style="width:120px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-size:15px;text-align-last:center;">              
                                <option> > </option>
                                <option> < </option>
                                <option> ≥ </option>
                                <option> ≤ </option>
                                <option> = </option>
                            </select>  
                            <input id="parameter" type="text" style="width:150px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-size:15px;text-align-last:center;">                                          
                            </input>                                                                 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">                                                    
                  <div class="col-md-4" id="showquery">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                       <div class="btn-group">             
                        <button id="result" class="btn btn-theme" type="submit" style="height:30px;width:100px;" onclick="return showQuery()">Show</button>

                        <button id="export" class="btn btn-theme" type="Export" style="height:30px;width:100px;" onclick="return ExportFile()">Export</button>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>

<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#export").click(function () {
        var urls = "{% url 'polls:export' %}";  
        var name = $('#columnselect').val();
        var table = $('#dataselect').val();
        var column = $('#conditionselect').val();
        var operator = $('#operator').val();
        var condition = $('#parameter').val();

        $.ajax({                     
          url: urls,                    
          data: {
            'name' : name,
            'table': table,
            'column' : column,
            'operator' : operator,
            'condition' : condition
          },
          success: function(data) {   
              alert("success")
          },
          error: function(data)
          {
            alert("error occured");
          }
        });
      });
      });

  </script>
  <script>
       function ExportFile()
    {
          return false
    }
    </script>
```

here's the views

```
def export(request):
    import cx_Oracle
    data_name = request.GET.get('name',1)
    table_name = request.GET.get('table',1)
    column_name = request.GET.get('column',1)
    operator = request.GET.get('operator',1)
    condition = request.GET.get('condition',1)
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('10.20.214.198', '1527', sid='dicb') 
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'icb', password='devicb', dsn=dsn_tns) 
    c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute("select "+data_name+" from "+table_name+" where "+column_name+operator+"'"+condition+"'")
    c.rowfactory = makeDictFactory(c)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'
    #writer = csv.writer( open("output.csv","w") )

    #writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
    #writer.writerow(['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    print(response)
    columnalldata = []
    for rowDict in c:
        columnalldata.append(rowDict[data_name])
        writer.writerow(rowDict[data_name])

    #context = {
    ##}

    return response
```

urls.py

```
 path('export/',views.export,name='export'),
```

i don't know where i am wrong , it seems like in documentation it can save as file

thankyou for help

Comment: What you can see when you visit `export/` url?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam when i try to klik export button on definesegment.html , it still directed to definesegment.html .. i think because of the ajax request that use the export url so it will run the export views in the website and didnt change the definesegment url

Comment: @AshrafulIslam when i click the export button , it shows the alert "Success" in popup form , but i didnt see any save as file or any file created , except if i use the #writer = csv.writer( open("output.csv","w") ) code.. but it didnt show the save as , and imedieately create the csv in my application folder without any notice

Comment: Creating a csv file in application that is doing in server. But you browser need to know there is a file and save it. Is it?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam yep , correct thats the point

Comment: just dont know how to do it .. i thought when i return response , its already download to save as , but i think im wrong

Comment: You can send the file relative path from server to client. For example, `something.zip`. So browser will notify you to save the file.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam in the ajax? or in the views

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204091/discussion-between-ashraful-islam-and-trytocode).